# Is there any function to find Duplicate of chars using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Write a python function, remove_duplicate() which accepts a string and removes all duplicate chars from a given string and return it.
Sample

Input:

```
1122334455ababzzz@@123#*#*
```

Output:

```
12345abz@#*
```

I tried this regular expression:

```
import re
re.subn(r'([(0-9)(a-z)])\1+', r'\1', Sample)
```

it gives me: `'12345ababz@@123#*#*'` not same as expected output.

Comment: You could use `Sets`

Comment: From python 3.6 onwards  you could do `''.join(dict.fromkeys(string))`

Comment: As the others have said, there are better tools for this task than regex. If you really want to use a regex somewhere, you can first reverse the string, replace `(.)(?=.*?\1)` with empty string, then reverse it again, but this solution is _really_ slow compared to, say, using a set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-ins like set(), but that might mess up the order. If you want to keep the order and only remove the repetitions, you can make a simple for loop:

```
test = "1122334455ababzzz@@123#*#*"

_out = ""
for x in test:
    if x not in _out:
        _out = _out+x

print(_out)
```

> > > 12345abz@#*

Comment: That's not a regular expression, which is what the OP asked in the Q

Comment: True, but why use Regex for something that is simple to solve with python itself?

Comment: It's in the eye of the observer :) some would consider this solution cumbersome. regex makes things simple. (e.g, 1 line instead of 4) and most of the time more efficient.

Comment: Also true, but the output is actually different. Compared to the other answer, I actually get the output OP is trying to get.